# Rails 3 with Devise for Authentication - How do I manually create a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, registration

I would like to manually create new `User`s, without forcing them to verify their email address.

The idea is to allow existing users to automatically add their friends without requiring their registration. It makes sense for the business case I'm working to solve.

How can this be achieved with Devise?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `skip_confirmation!` method is available to any `confirmable` model.

```
@user = User.new params[:user]
@user.skip_confirmation! # Sets confirmed_at to Time.now, activating the account
@user.save
```

The user account will be activated though. If you don't want that, continue reading.

Devise uses conditional callbacks to generate the confirmation token and send the email. The callbacks will be called only if `confirmation_required?` returns `true`. Redefine it on your model:

```
def confirmation_required?
  false
end
```

However, this will make the `active_for_authentication?` method always return true because it takes whether or not confirmation is required into account. We have to redefine that as well:

```
def active_for_authentication?
  confirmed? || confirmation_period_valid?
end
```

This way, the account will stay inactive and no confirmation email will be sent. You will have to manually activate the user by calling `confirm!` on the record or just setting `confirmed_at` to any date.

It's quite a hack, but it should work.

For reference: [confirmable.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb)

Comment: thank you. but I don't want the user to be able to log-in. will setting the user to confirmed allow the user to some how login? what will that do, just prevent emails from being sent? thanks

Comment: Also, when I try to save a new user like you mentioned above i get FALSE on @user.save.... besides an email, what other fields are required to save a user?

Comment: I updated my answer. Any fields that are marked as not null on your schema or whose presence your model validates for are required. If you don't provide them Active Record will not save your object.

Comment: If you want to create a user only with email address, then you can deactivate the validation by u.save(:validate => false)

Comment: active? is renamed to active_for_authentication? (from devise version 1.2.0)

Answer (score 9):

I just want to add for future reference that since Devise 2.2 there is now a `skip_confirmation_notification!` method available as well which basically does everything from Matheus' post without redefining the methods in the model.