# Devise skip_confirmation! method confirms user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my Ruby on Rails application I have multi step with wicked gem to create customer registration. I want to send confirmation at the last step so in my controller I use devise method:

```
@customer.skip_confirmation!
```

But this method is not sending confirmation email and automatically confirm customer. I don't want to have confirmed customer when he didn't click the link in mail. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There is a good answer here:

[Rails 3 with Devise for Authentication - How do I manually create a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599226/rails-3-with-devise-for-authentication-how-do-i-manually-create-a-user#answer-4599390)

It explains that `skip_confirmation!` method sets `confirmed_at`, and also supplies a workaround which allows you to skip confirmation without *confirming* the user.

Answer (score 1):

> If you don't want confirmation to be sent on create, neither a code to
>   be generated, call [skip_confirmation!](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable)

if you have added in your user.rb (model) the confirmable module, than the confirmation will be send by it self, right after the user have been created. So you don't need to add something in your controller other than @user.create!